# CSS :after element being pushed to new line

Tags: css

I'm trying to set up a navbar with separators before and after each list item. Everything seems to work fine in Chrome and IE, but in Firefox the last separator is being pushed down to another line.

I've cut out all the extraneous code I can, but tried to leave anything that might be responsible for this. And I've temporarily replaced the separator image with an "x" for this example, it works the same.

I've confirmed the behavior is duplicated in each browser in this JSFiddle, so you'll have to view it in Firefox to see the issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/WGCyu/548/

You can also recreate the problem in Chrome/IE by changing **WIDTH** from 4px to anything greater than or equal to 6px in the following section:

```
nav ul > li:before, nav ul > li:last-of-type:after {
    content:"x";
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    top: -2px;
    left: -2px;
    width:4px; /* change to 6px or more to recreate issue in Chrome */
    height:70px;
}
```

Apologies if I just missed something stupid. And thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So because the `a` tag is between `:before` and `:after`, and the `:before` tag is `float:left`; you need to add `float:left` the `a` in order for the `:after` to `float:right` properly.

**Add this**

```
nav ul > li > a {
    float: left;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WGCyu/550/

Comment: Thank you, you are a god among men! I replaced the "display: inline-block" with "float:left" and everything worked, just like you said it would! So, my follow-up question is, why doesn't inline-block work in this situation? I thought it forced the elements to display "inline", meaning, one after another on the same row...? No?

Comment: Sure np. So as I mentioned in my solution, `display:inline-block` doesn't float the element which is why the `float:right` on the `:after` wasn't being picked up.